# How does one establish that the set of even and odd numbers partition the set of integers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

**Question:**

How does one establish that the set of even and odd numbers partition the set of integers?

In short, how do we know that all integers are either even or odd?

Comment: The notion of even and odd only makes sense for integers.

Comment: What is you definition for an even real number?

Comment: You mean that $\pi$ is even!! or odd!!

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake. I meant the set of integers.

Comment: By showing that no integer is both odd and even, and showing that every integer is either odd or even.

Comment: If $n$ is an integer, then by the division algorithm, there are unique integers $q$ and $r$ such that $n = 2q + r$ where $r$ is either $0$ or $1$. In the former case, we say that $n$ is even; in the latter case, we say that $n$ is odd. Since these are the only two possibilities, by definition all integers are either even or odd.

Comment: @Bungo: You are right, of course. To go even deeper, one can prove that the only natural numbers less than $2$ are $0$ and $1$ by first proving by induction that the only natural number less than $1$ is $0$.

Comment: @Bungo Formally an equivalence relation does the job. You need to prove your assertion first.

Comment: @AaronMaroja: Seems to me that the division algorithm is fundamental here. Without it, or something equivalent, how will you conclude (referring to your answer below) that $\overline{0}$ and $\overline{1}$ are the only equivalence classes?

Comment: @Bungo Sure, but the algorithm itself does not garantee a partition. That's where the equivalence relation comes in.

Comment: @AaronMaroja: It does guarantee a partition. The division algorithm tells us that for each integer $n$, there is a uniquely determined integer $r$ satisfying $0 \leq r < 2$, and the only integers in this range are $0$ and $1$. So we get a partition of $\mathbb{Z}$ into those integers with a remainder of $0$ and those with a remainder of $1$.

Comment: @Bungo which is $\equiv$ modulo $2$ in $\mathbb Z$, by definition. And as long an equivalence relation in a space decomposes this space in a disjoint reunion of equivalent classes then we have a partition.

Comment: @AaronMaroja: Sure, the only point I wanted to make is that you said "you need to prove your assertion [the division algorithm] first", but I believe your argument will also require the division algorithm.

Comment: @Bungo $a \equiv b \mod n \iff b -a \in I(n)$. Where $I(n)$ is an ideal.

Comment: This is one of those deceptively simple questions the answer to which we normally take for granted.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite the stumper. Of course each integer is either odd or even! I know it and I believe it. But how to prove it to someone who neither knows it nor believes it?

I guess we'd have to start with the very basics, with those facts we normally think need no explanation, like, what is an integer? Zero is an integer and one is another integer; if our nonbeliever accepts these two facts, maybe we can get him to accept the fact that each integer is either even or odd.

An integer is any number that can be obtained by repeatedly adding one to zero, or by repeatedly subtracting one from zero. You can obtain $-47$, 1729 and a googolplex this way, to give just three examples (of course, in the case of a googolplex it would be extremely tedious). You can't obtain $\frac{1}{2}$ nor $\pi$ this way. We say that the integers are "closed under addition" (which of course also includes subtraction and multiplication). Adding an integer to another integer results in an integer. The same goes for the subtraction and multiplication of integers.

So then what is an even integer? Any number that can be obtained by repeatedly adding 2 to zero, or by repeatedly subtracting 2 from zero. If $n$ is an integer, then so is $2n$. We can then say that an even integer is a number of the form $2n$, provided it's clear that $n$ is also an integer.

And what is an odd integer? A number of the form $2n + 1$, where, again, as before, $n$ is also an integer. Given another integer $m$, notice that $2m + 2n = 2(m + n)$, which is also even, and $(2m + 1) + (2n + 1) = 2(m + n + 1)$, which again is even, but $2m + (2n + 1) = 2(m + n) + 1$, which is odd.

Zero is even, which can be verified by the fact that $2 \times 0 = 0$. And one is odd, which can be verified with $2 \times 0 + 1 = 1$. Normally, all the foregoing would be way too obvious and basic to be worth mentioning. But this kind of rigor (or dullness, some might say) is necessary to give an answer more satisfying than "That's just the way it is."

If there exists an integer $x$ which is neither even nor odd, it can be expressed as $0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + \ldots + 1$ (the dots stand in for a bunch more "$+ \, 1$"s) or $0 - 1 - 1 - 1 - \ldots - 1$ (the dots stand in for a bunch more "$- \, 1$"s), *but* it *can't* be expressed as $2n$ nor $2n + 1$.

Now take the "unary" representation of $x$, and, starting at the left, replace the first occurrence of "$+ \, 1 + 1$" with "$+ \, 2$", or the first occurrence of "$- \, 1 - 1$" with "$- \, 2$". If there's another instance of "$+ \, 1 + 1$" or "$- \, 1 - 1$", replace it accordingly. Keep going until there's only a "$+ \, 1$" or "$- \, 1$" left, or maybe you only have a zero followed by a bunch of 2's separated by plus or minus signs.

How many 2's have you written? The number of 2's is an integer: write another zero above the zero and a 1 above each 2, and plus or minus signs between them to match, call $n$ the number represented by this expression. By the definition given earlier, $n$ is an integer. You have written $n$ 2's. If every 1 was paired up, this means $x = 2n$. But if there was a single 1 left on the right after a whole bunch of 2's, then $x = 2n + 1$. But this contradicts the earlier assertion that $x$ can't be represented in this way, meaning that $x$ is either odd or even.

---

If you want to be super formal about it, you can say that $\langle 2 \rangle$ and its coset $\langle 2 \rangle + 1$ (or $1 + \langle 2 \rangle$, same thing) form all of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Through the equivalence relation $\equiv \mod 2$ you may get this result. You'll have

$$\mathbb Z_2=\{\overline 0, \overline 1\}$$

which is a partition of $\mathbb Z$.